# why i am getting type error in my JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

why am i getting this error ?

i am learning web development from colt steele webd bootcamp and i got this error.

```
$ node user.js
mongo connection is open
D:\web development practice\mongoose_relationship\Models\user.js:44
    u.addresses.push({
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addresses')
    at addAddress (D:\web development practice\mongoose_relationship\Models\user
.js:44:7)
```

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/relationshipDemo', { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("mongo connection is open")
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log("oh no mongoose connection error");
        console.log(e);
    })

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    first: String,
    last: String,
    addresses: [{
        _id: { id: false },
        street: String,
        city: String,
        state: String,
        country: String
    }]
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

const makeUser = async () => {
    const u = new User({
        first: 'Harry',
        last: 'Potter'
    })
    u.addresses.push({
        street: 'baker street',
        city: 'london',
        state: 'london',
        country: 'uk'
    })
    await User.deleteMany();
    const res = await u.save();
    console.log(res);
}

const addAddress = async (id) => {
    const u = await User.findById(id);
    u.addresses.push({
        street: 'florida street',
        city: 'new york',
        state: 'new york',
        country: 'usa',
    })
    const res = await u.save();
    console.log(res);
}

addAddress('62ceae58cbb52805b8150ce9');
```

Comment: @epascarello i cross verified the id is correct.

Comment: on which line you get error `makeUser` or `getAddress` function.

Comment: @MohitSharma on ``getAddress``

Comment: Does the user with the given ID `62ceae58cbb52805b8150ce9` exists? It's just that `await User.findById("62ceae58cbb52805b8150ce9");` returns `null`, therefor you get  the error.

Comment: as i see in code first of all console.log(u?.addresses) so you see that addresses key really exist or not

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you're missing a semicolon ";" after your parentheses.

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: Semicolons in JavaScript are optional

Comment: @KonradLinkowski not always. There are [rules for the automatic insertion](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-rules-of-automatic-semicolon-insertion) of a semicolon.